# Cannot unlist a list coerced from a call object in R?

Tags: r

Here is the experiment:

```
myfunc = function(a, b, c) {
    callobj = match.call()
    save(callobj, file="/tmp/callobj.rda")
}
myfunc(11, 22, 33)
load("/tmp/callobj.rda")
x = unlist(as.list(callobj))
print(x)
x = unlist(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
print(x)
```

Results:

```
> myfunc(11, 22, 33)
> load("/tmp/callobj.rda")
> x = unlist(as.list(callobj))
> print(x)
[[1]]
myfunc

$a
[1] 11

$b
[1] 22

$c
[1] 33

> x = unlist(list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3))
> print(x)
a b c 
1 2 3
```

The question is, why on the earth do the two lists behave differently? One of them can be unlisted, the other, apparently, cannot.

As suggested in one of the comments, I did this:

```
> dput(as.list(callobj))
structure(list(myfunc, a = 11, b = 22, c = 33), .Names = c("", 
"a", "b", "c"))
> dput(list(a = 1, b = 2))
structure(list(a = 1, b = 2), .Names = c("a", "b"))
```

Doesn't explain why the two lists are different in behavior.

Comment: I did use as.list(callobj)

Comment: ^^ Realized that as hitting enter

Comment: Look at `dput(as.list(callobj))`

Comment: @SeñorO edited again.

Comment: See also `unlist(list("aa", a = 2, v = 3))` and `unlist(list(as.symbol("aa"), a = 2, v = 3))`

Comment: @alexis_laz Nice catch, man! Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: @qed : In addition, I'm not entirely sure, but in [`do_unlist`](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/bind_8c.html#a8e4a6fbb8216e1465308786d40428937) there is a comment that notes that the return is a "list" if a non-vector is encountered; `is.vector(as.symbol("xx"))`; `is.vector("xx")`. Perhaps, someone could organize a compact answer better..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `as.character` on `call` objects.

This would be equivalent to the unlisted, unnamed call to `as.list(callobj)`.

```
> as.character(callobj)
# [1] "myfunc" "11"     "22"     "33"
```

To unlist `callobj`, we need all the elements to be of the same type.  We can't have characters, numerics, and calls all in the same vector. R does not allow mixed object types in the same vector.

But we can use `deparse` and get it done:

```
> sapply(as.list(callobj), deparse)
#                 a        b        c 
# "myfunc"     "11"     "22"     "33"
```

This also makes apparent one of the main differences between `sapply` and `lapply`.  We don't need `unlist` for this if we use `sapply`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `dput(unlist(callobj))`:

```
structure(list(myfunc, a = 11, b = 22, c = 33), .Names = c("", 
"a", "b", "c"))
```

`myfunc` is still in there. You can't unlist a list if there's no simpler represenation to coerce it to:

```
> unlist(list(function(x) x + 1, 3))
[[1]]
function (x) 
x + 1

[[2]]
[1] 3
```